# how to fix getJSON method error in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, getjson

hello guys i am getting the following errors :

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $.getJSON is not a function TypeError: $.getJSON is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost/whatever/js/super.js:15:4)
    at j (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2:30164)
    at k (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2:30478) undefined
r.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2
jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $.getJSON is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (super.js:15)
    at j (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2)
```

my json code is this :

```js
 $.getJSON('../whatever/data/comments.json', function (data) {
  var commentStr = '<ul class="list-unstyled">';
  $.each(data , function (i ,item) {
   // body...
   commentStr += '<li class="media my-4">';
   commentStr += '<img class="d-flex mr-3" src="..." alt="Generic placeholder image">';
   commentStr += '<div class="media-body">';
   commentStr += '<h5 class="mt-0 mb-1">'+ item.name +'</h5>';
   commentStr += '' + item.comment + '</div></li>';
  });
  $("#comment").html("commentStr");
 });
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: the problem is not on the client side, but the server replying with "forbidden". check your settings for the respective file/folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include full version of JQuery. Seems like you are using a `slim` version. Probably that doesn't include `$.getJSON()` function and other `ajax` call functions. Hence the Error - `Uncaught TypeError: $.getJSON is not a function`.

So use -

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

in your `head` tag.